# Is it possible to force page breaks when styling for printing?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page consisting of a dynamically generated report and when printing out the page, it usually spans to multiple printed pages. The content is grouped within divs and when printing a lot of times the content within the divs will get cut from one page to the next. Is there any way to style this so that if a div gets cut from one page to the next, instead somehow have a page break inserted so that each page will only contain the divs in their entirety (with no cut-offs)?

Comment: [page-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)

Comment: Have you considered using a print stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use page-break
here is a doc
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.